# Ubuntu 14.04 Live USB - Boots, then reboots?

Tags: boot, 14.04, live-usb, system-installation, amd-processor

I downloaded an Ubuntu 14.04 ISO from the Ubuntu webiste, and then installed it via LinuxLive USB creator using 13.10 parameters.

If I boot from it from my AMD A10-5800K system, it will get in and I can even start running programs, but then it will just end and reboot.

I'd appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Format your USB stick, and make bootable usb again using `UNetbootin`: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
Did you make 64bit live usb? Make sure your pc support it.